remove legends from ggplot
I would like to remove the circle legend in the Figure. 
I am using the following code
ggplot(df2, aes(x = genotype, y = sum, fill = label,colour=label)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), width = 0.8)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(df2$sum), linetype="dashed",color = "black", linewidth=0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = sum, ymax = sum + sd), width = 0.4,
                position = position_dodge(0.9)) + theme_bw()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#abebc6','#2ecc71','#1d8348'))+
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c('Sensitive','Moderate', 'Tolerant'),
    values = c('#abebc6','#2ecc71','#1d8348'))+
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)+scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.1))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 25))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8,face = "bold", angle=90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8, face = "bold"),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(face = "bold"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.8, 0.95), 
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.key.size = unit(5, 'mm'),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10,family = "serif",face="bold"))


Change legend.position to "none", or add show.legend = FALSE to your geom_* calls, or add guide = "none" to your scale_* calls.

@zephryl thanks for the help. I need one more thing to do. in this fig, actually green color bars (1st, 4,5,7,8,11,....) are grouped as sensitive in data and light green bars are Moderate but it is shown as vice versa. How can I change the color of the bars accordingly while legends stays the same. (I want to show green bars as light green and light green as green and dark green stays the same and also legends stays the same)
